# Forms, multiple selects leads to sub-questions for each selection

Tags: google-forms

Can this kind of form be made with Google forms?

**Problem:**

First page: user checks few boxes from the menu.

Second page: for each of the first page selects - few options are given.

**Example**, user selects 1 and 3 from the first page:

**First page:**

- Salad - √
- Soup  - X
- Lunch - √

**Second page:**

*Salad options:*

- green
- red

*Lunch options:*

- vege
- meat

Answer (score 1):

Google does have a `Go to section based on answer` feature, although that feature doesn't work with checkboxes. The feature only works with `Radio` and `Dropdown` question types. You could theoretically use radio or dropdown questions to accomplish that, although the user would need to answer "No" or leave it blank for everything they don't want.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Multiple selects can't be used to decide what shows on the next form page.

## Explanation

Google Forms has a navigation control. It could be use to decide which form section will be shown but not to decide which questions will be shown based on the options selected on a checkbox question.

## References

[Control navigation to sections of a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/141062?hl=en)